# Unable to change visibility of a div in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, visibility

I have a div that displays loading symbol. I am setting visibility on change of a dropdown box. I want to set its visibility to false in C# after the `SelectedIndexChanged` method is complete.

Here is the **div** tag :

```
<div runat="server" clientidmode="Static" id="loadingImage" class="loadingImage" >
 <img class="loadingImg" src="../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

Here is the **jQuery** function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#loadingImage').hide();
    var modal = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    modal.style.display = "none";

    $("#selectSegment").change(function () {
        var modal = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
        modal.style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

and this is how i am trying to set the visibility in **C#**

```
protected void selectSegment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ckBLBusinessUnits.Visible = true;
    loadingImage.Style["display"] = "none";
}
```

I tried various ways in C# like set visibility to false etc but nothing worked. Kindly help.

Comment: Is your `selectSegment` control set to AutoPostback=true?

Comment: @Ishan In your jQuery change event the display is being set to block and in the SelectIndexChanged event it is being set to none. I believe the display setting you are making in the jQuery is overriding the one you made in SelectIndexChanged event

Comment: @Marco Yes right, the control is as follows `<asp:DropDownList ID="selectSegment" runat="server" name="selectSegment" AutoPostBack="True"  class="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectSegment_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: @Sujith i tried setting an alert but the event doesn't get fired again.

Comment: The control is inside the updatepanel. Should that have any impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div tag was outside of the `updatepanel`, moving the `div` inside of the `updatepanel` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
loadingImage.Style["display"] = "none";
```

To this:

```
loadingImage.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hide and show methods to perform that action.

```
<div runat="server" clientidmode="Static" id="loadingImage" class="loadingImage">

 <img class="loadingImg" src="loading.gif" />
</div>


        <asp:DropDownList ID="selectSegment" ClientIDMode="Static" 
 runat="server">

            <asp:ListItem Value="0">none</asp:ListItem>

            <asp:ListItem Value="1">display</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                var modal = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
                modal.style.display = "none";

                $("#selectSegment").change(function () {


                    if (this.value === "1") {
                        $("#loadingImage").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#loadingImage").hide();
                    }


                });
            });
```